# Issues converting a saved model to tfjs format

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I'm converting a saved model to tfjs format. However, the file group1-shard1of1.bin is super small (16 bytes) and almost certainly wrong. Has anyone encountered this issue in the past? I've tried both the tensorflowjs_wizard as well as using the regular script

tensorflowjs_converter 
--input_format=tf_saved_model 
--output_format=tfjs_graph_model 
--signature_name=serving_default 
--saved_model_tags=serve 
saved_model 
web_model